# Prettyphoto loads on at page beginning horizontal 1page website

Tags: jquery, html, css, overlay, lightbox

I am currently implementing PrettyPhoto into a horizontal 1page website:
http://www.basenharald.nl/3d (click foto & video for the section i am talking about)

In a way the script works.
If you click the first photo (only one that is linked) you will notice that something is happening.
What actually is happening is that the overlay with photo loads at the beginning of the page (scroll wayyy left to start to see it)

How can i make it so that the image will show at the current location as overlay?

Script can be found at http://www.basenharald.nl/3d/js/scripts.js but it is minified (for some reason the uncompressed version was not available for download)

Help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to achieve and what your problem is.

Comment: Click the image, then scroll way to the left... that is where prettyphoto loads, not at the current place on the page.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work on Firefox... but I see it in IE9.

Comment: oh that could be. I am sorry, did not test in in FF yet.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work on Safari either... :-/

Comment: I can't find the linked photo. The uncompressed code *is* available on the PrettyPhoto page. Have you contacted its author? Have you tried one of the countless other lightbox clones?

Comment: The linked photo is the topleft one. I havent contacted the author yet. Will do that if i cannot find my answer here.

Comment: @Luuk: Using Chrome the top left photo isn't linked. I can't see a link in the source code either.

Comment: jeez, i see. seems to only work in IE9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself by simply adding this line of css:

```
div.light_rounded, div.dark_rounded, div.facebook, 
div.light_square, div.dark_square, div.pp_overlay { position: fixed; }
```

Thought it would be nice to answer it here for others

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have additional help for you on this issue.

While you solved the problem of making the right content appear at the right place, you still have a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the page. I assume you don't really want this, since it looks ugly and your intended navigation is the eight links in your footer that use javascript to scroll the page to the correct screen.

All you have to do to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar that's still left is add the following style:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Hope this helps finalize your solution.

Comment: I will ofcourse do this in the end when all is finished. For editing it is easier to scroll. When finished i will disable scrollbars and add a preloader since the website is becomming rather big.

Comment: Good deal, best of luck with it!